# How to call custom script in Orchard CMS

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, content-management-system, orchardcms

How to call custom script in Layout.cshtml ?

This is CMS platform based  on the MVC razor

Print screen: http://prntscr.com/m71t3g

Success load of the all scripts

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the Document.cshtml?

May be you forgot to add this at the end of the body:

```
@Display(Model.Tail)
```